# HTML ссылка на директорию

Tags: html, node.js

С адреса `localhost/files/testfolder`открывается ссылка на директорию `file.txt` и открывается страница с адресом не `localhost/files/testfolder/file.txt`(как ожидалось)
, а `localhosy/files/file.txt`. Почему так происходит и как исправить?

HTML файл:

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
     <h2>Files</h2>
  <a href="file.txt">Open file</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Код сервера Node JS

```
app.get("/files/*", function(req, res) {
    path = req.params[0];
    path = "files/" + path;

    try {
        var stats = fs.statSync(path);

        if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
                res.render("files.ejs");
            });
        }

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error");
    }
});
```

Comment: вы что-то не дописали во второй части, но как я понял у вас не абсолютная ссылка и ведет она в ту папку, в которой находитесь

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev может можно как-то сделать что-бы тег ссылки просто добавлял к url "/file.txt"?

Comment: да, но путь надо писать от корня до файла - `/files/testfolder/file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Переделал вот так и заработало:

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
        <h2>Files</h2>
  <a href="/openfolder/file.txt">Open file</a>
 </body>
</html>
```